# Updating an app that was installed by package installer

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app that was installed by 800 user by package installer (not google play) but now I will publish this app in Google play with new version code an I want that users update to new version in Google play. How I do it? I made a test with another app and did not occur update.

Comment: Updates will be notified ***ONLY and EXCLUSIVELY*** through the official Play Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Play will not update apps installed via package installer. You will have to ask your users to re-install from Play by communicating with them.